# Installing windows to a new hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

Go easy on me - my first post here!

I want to install windows on my new hard drive. I have the install files on my old hard drive, I purchased windows 7 online and have downloaded those files. I can either :

Put the install files onto a USB - but didn't know if I could install windows 7 from a USB to a new blank hard drive.

-OR-

Install windows to my new hard drive from my old one.

What do you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you try using the [Windows 7 USB Download Tool](http://lifehacker.com/5423747/windows-7-usb-download-tool-lets-you-install-windows-from-a-thumb-drive) which allows you to create a bootable flash drive that you can install Windows 7 from.

[image]